# NGINX health check requires an upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a location like:

```
location / {
set $api_name "Web";

proxy_intercept_errors on;

set $upstream upstream_a;

if ( $kms_in_cookie != "not_set" ) {
    set $upstream $kms_in_cookie;
}

if ( $upstream_in_cookie != "not_set" ) {
    set $upstream $upstream_in_cookie;
}

if ($cookie_zak != "") {
    set $upstream upstream_b;
}

proxy_pass http://$upstream;

health_check uri=/healthcheck  interval=30 fails=3 passes=3;}
```

Once I restart my NGINX, it failed:

```
nginx: [emerg] health check requires an upstream in
```

Any one has a idea about this? What does this error mean?

Comment: I have the same bug, do you know what it means?

Comment: Same bug too. Any updates on this ?

Comment: As I konw, when using health_check, you cannot make upstream changeable.

Comment: I have the same bug. I couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. From experimenting with it the issue appears to be the variable name in the `proxy_pass` directive. If you use the name of a valid upstream the issue is resolved.

Clearly you are trying to direct traffic based on some request meta-data, and the above advice wont help with this. Your scenario is not an uncommon one so I would expect this to work. Looks like a bug in nginx, or at the very least a gap in the documentation.